# Django Rest Framework + S3: ImageField View Count

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I use DRF for a frontend client and use S3 for hosting my images. Is there any reliably good way to fetch the total times an image has been viewed? Sort of like a hit-counter or YouTube style "view count" for the image?

- Ideally, if S3 could return some sort of times an image has been fetched that would be the best way to increment the counter, but I don't see a reliable way to do that.
- I could also make a network request every time an image on my client is "expanded", marking a view but that seems clunky.

Any good ideas for incrementing image view count w/ DRF?

Comment: on every get request, you can also manually increment the counter, just have an extra field in the model. or may be do async.